# inverse function of Chi-Square distribution in PHP?

Tags: php, math, statistics

does anyone have the inverse chi-square distribution as a PHP function? I basically need the equiv. of excel function CHIINV but useable in PHP.

or can anyone write this function in PHP? big huge thanks to anyone that does.

excel function info taken from microsoft site:
CHIINV(p, df) is the inverse function for CHIDIST(x, df). For any particular x, CHIDIST(x, df) returns the probability that a Chi-Square-distributed random variable with df degrees of freedom is greater than or equal to x.

Comment: Have you tried the stats library in PECL? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-cdf-chisquare.php

Comment: they don't have inverse of chi-square though

Comment: It is supposed to be able to do chi-square inverse, [but it's broken](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=14909). I was able to make it work by replacing dcdflib with a different version as suggested [here](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17637). Depending on the degree of accuracy you need, it may be easier to use a lookup table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually here i did the work:

```
function AChiSq($p,$n) { 
$v=0.5;
$dv=0.5; 
$x=0;
    while($dv>1e-15) {
        $x=1/$v-1;
        $dv=$dv/2;
        if (ChiSq($x,$n)>$p) {
            $v=$v-$dv;
        }
        else {
            $v=$v+$dv;
        } 
    }
    return $x;
}
function Norm($z) {
    $q=$z*$z;
   if (abs($z)>7)
        return (1-1/$q+3/($q*$q))*exp(-$q/2)/(abs($z)*sqrt($PiD2));
    else
        return ChiSq($q,1);
}
function ChiSq($x,$n) {
    if ($x>1000 || $n>1000) {
            $q=Norm((pow($x/$n,1/3)+2/(9*$n)-1)/sqrt(2/(9*$n)))/2;
            if ($x>$n) 
                return $q;
            else
                return 1-$q; 
        }
    $p=exp(-0.5*$x);
        if(($n%2)==1) { $p=$p*sqrt(2*$x/$Pi);       }
    $k=$n; 
        while($k>=2) {
        $p=$p*$x/$k;
        $k=$k-2;
        }
   $t=$p;
     $a=$n;
     while($t>1e-15*$p) {
        $a=$a+2;
        $t=$t*$x/$a; 
        $p=$p+$t;
        }

    return 1-$p;
}
function calppm($conf,$fails,$total)
{
    $E5 = $conf/100;
  $F5 = $fails;
  $G5 = $total;

    $I5 = AChiSq((1-$E5),(2*($F5+1)))*1000000/(2*$G5);

    return round($I5);
}

//echo calppm(60,0,50000); //18
?>
```